# Why the <receiver> that I declare in AndroidManifest.xml not registered to the system when the device boot completed

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have coding an apk to start my service when the system started,this apk not has any activities. I just declare a  in it's AndroidManifest.xml,but the receiver not registered to system when the system boot completed.

The android platform is Android 9.0. I need to upgrade my system from O to P.

1.I have tested on the android 8.1, this application can register the receiver and received the broadcast to start the Service when the system boot completed.

2.I have checked the /data/system/packages.xml in my android device,my application already exist.

3.I use this command to check the receivers that registered to system,but the  that I declared in manifest.xml is not exist.

```
adb shell sumpsys activitys b 'com.xxx.xxx.xxservice'
```

4.I use this command to check the application that is exist too.

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep 'com.xxx.xxx.xxservice'
```

5.I have tested it on SELinux ON/OFF,the result is the same. Did not register the receiver.

6.And there have another application like this in the system,it can registerd it's receiver and receive the same broadcast(com.xxx.xxx.FAST_BOOT).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.xxx.xxx.xxservice"
      android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">

    <permission android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX_SERVICE_PERMISSION"
        android:label="@string/xxxService"
        android:description="@string/xxxService"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.RECEIVE_FAST_BOOT" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:process="system">

        <uses-library android:name="ServiceUtils" />

        <receiver android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AppReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xxx.xxx.FAST_BOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Service" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: We have added a broadcast when the system boot completeed，and it will send success. Because the receiver in other application‘s manifest.xml can received it.

Now when the system boot completed，it will send this broadcast.

`public static final String ACTION_FAST_BOOT = "android.intent.action.FAST_BOOT"`

and it need this permission that I already declared in manifest.xml.

`<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.RECEIVE_FAST_BOOT" />`

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: We have added a broadcast when the system boot completeed，and it will send success. Because the receiver in other application‘s manifest.xml can received it.

Now when the system boot completed，it will send this broadcast.

```
public static final String ACTION_FAST_BOOT = "android.intent.action.FAST_BOOT"
```

and it need this permission that I already declared in manifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.RECEIVE_FAST_BOOT" />
```